# Screen to view time slots for a particular date in Angular

Tags: angular7, angular9

I need a screen to show the time slots for selected date as below. All the data shown here will be taken from database using API calls. I want an similar UI in Angular 7 or later by which I can implement this functionality.

[image]

I need help in getting the UI part implemented using Angular for dates to be show in horizontal scroller.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to Angular I need an UI where I can show the calendar dates as show in the above image(horizontal scroller) instead of normal date picker.

Comment: Alright. So, what have you tried? Please post some code so that the community can help you.